# Neurones and putting on clothes (Pacinian Corpuscle)

Tags: neuroscience

If I put on clothes, a gentle pressure is applied to the Pacinian corpuscles in the skin, causing Na+ ion channels to open and an action potential to be initiated - hence I feel the clothes on my skin.

However, I was reading that after prolonged time, the action potentials are no longer generated unless there is another change in pressure as the clothes again move over the surface over the skin.

I'm confused why. The reason I am given is that the Na+ ion channels remain open so a resting potential cannot be established, but I can't see how this contributes to the effect.

Can someone explain why?